# Is there a way to make vim automatically add a space at the beginning of a comment?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'm setting up my .vimrc for learning Python. So far I have:

```
" configure expansion of tabs for .py files
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py set expandtab

set expandtab       " Use spaces instead of TAB
set tabstop=2       " One TAB equals 2 spaces
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2    " Spaces to use for autoindent
set autoindent      " Copy indent from current line on new line   
set ruler       " show line and column number
syntax on       " syntax highlighting
set smartindent

" keep indentation on comments (#)
" http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restoring_indent_after_typing_hash
:inoremap # X<BS>#
```

My question is -- every time I start a line with a `#`, it is a comment and to make it pretty I always add a space after the hash. Is there a way to ask `vim` to insert said space automagically? It doesn't necessarily need to be at the beginning of the line, though that would be ideal.

Comment: I've defined a user command if I have to comment more than one line:
command! -range CommentShellScript <line1>,<line2>s/^/# /g

Then I do a VISUAL LINE select and execute it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to *~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim*:

```
inoremap # #<space>
```

Alternatively, you can add this setting to your vimrc file by adding the following line:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py inoremap # #<space>
```

Comment: I don't know. I tried it and it didn't work. I tried it with both `<space>` and also with just a space character, `inoremap # # `. Neither one did the trick.

Comment: Just retested it. Works for me. Perhaps try setting it manually by opening up a python file, typing `:inoremap # #<space>`, and then hitting the enter key. Then retest. If that works, the problem is that your vim is not checking the _python.vim_ file I listed for some reason.

Comment: I've edited this solution to include a description of how to set this mapping from your vimrc file.

Comment: I'd never heard of the `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` folder before and it didn't exist on my system. Like a good *NIXer, I did some research and found that in order to enable the `ftplugin` folder, I had to add `filetype plugin` to my `.vimrc` file. After that it worked, though it broke some of my indentation. Still fiddling with it.

Comment: @StephenC Read `:h filetype-plugin` and `:h startup`. To override settings in a `ftplugin` you need to do that in a corresponding file placed in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin`. It's worth spending 5 minutes to understand how things are supposed to work together.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, thanks for the unnecessary jab. As I stated earlier, I AM learning about ftplugin and have spent much more than five minutes.

Comment: @StephenC Why do you think I was criticizing you? Why would I do that to begin with? Believe it or not, I was genuinely giving you a few pointers that I find useful. _shrug_